# How can I fix Dependency Error Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I was trying to migrate my Places SDK to the new places sdk. but after placing all required  dependencies, the IDE reports dependency errors.

These are the errors

`Duplicate class com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteActivity found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:2.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.zza found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:2.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.zzb found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:2.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.zzc found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:2.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.zzd found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:2.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0)`

Here are my dependencies

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-java:3.0.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-      compat:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar:verticalseekbar:0.7.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please take a look into this:
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-places-demos/issues/3

Answer (score 0):

Just delete this dependency
`implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0'`

use only `'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:2.0.0'` issue will resolved.

Comment: Yeah, that was the mistake: https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#initialize_the_new_places_sdk_client Note: You can only install either the client library or the compatibility library, NOT both.